Renew/Rotate refresh token with spring security 6 OAuth server
How can we enable refresh tokens to be auto-renewed(rotated) when a request is made with refresh_token grant_type. Currently the access token is renewed everytime is request is made but the refresh_token remains same until it expires. I want to get a new access & new refresh_token everytime.
I am using spring security 6
I want to extend the session of the user based on this activity & thats what I am trying to acheive by doing this.

Set reuseRefreshTokens to false in the TokenSettings of the RegisteredClient.
